# Compact subsets of Polish spaces

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, polish-spaces

I am interested in finding additional weak enough conditions for the following theorem to be true.

Let $X$ be a Polish space (that is, separable and completely metrizable), then if $\Omega \subset X$ is bounded, there exists a compact subset $K \subset X$ such that $\Omega \subset K$

Motivation: the theorem is by Heine-Borel true for finite dimensional real vector spaces (so $\mathbb{R}^d$'s in disguise) and my intuition tells me that if we impose separability, it is not too much of a stretch to go from a countable cover of some kind of extension of $\Omega$ (i.e. $\bar{\Omega}_{\epsilon}$ where $\Omega_{\epsilon}$ denotes the $\epsilon$ ball covering of $\Omega$ and bar denotes the closure) to a finite cover using some kind of neat trick or a weak additional assumption. I am trying to generalize a result I found in which $\Omega$ lies in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and in which this assumption of there being a great enough closed ball containing $\Omega$ is crucial for the rest of the argument.

Any hints, possible directions or other help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The unit ball in a countable-dimensional Hilbert space is bounded but not compact.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I already considered this, but I am not necessarily interested in finding a $K$ that is some form of a ball or union of countable balls. I would be interested in whether the unit ball $B$ for instance in this space could be contained in some other compact set $K \subset X$ where $X$ in your context is our beloved $\ell^{2}$

Comment: That's impossible, since any closed subset of a compact set is itself compact (in Hausdorff spaces).

Comment: A closed subset of a compact set is compact.  So if $B$ is closed and not compact, it can't be contained in some other compact set $K$.

Comment: The unit ball in $\ell^2$ contains a closed $1/2$-unit ball $\Omega$ If your wish came true,  $\Omega$ would be compact.  Which it isn't.

Comment: Ah of course, thanks! I should have thought that through more thoroughly. So it seems that a bounded subset in a separable complete space is not enough. So we should take $\Omega$ to be non-closed for my wishes to have a chance to materialize.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ in the discrete $0$-$1$ metric does not obey it, even though it's locally compact and $\sigma$-compact. And the irrationals are Polish and in that space even an open ball (so bounded) is not contained in a compact subset.

Comment: "Bounded" is not a topological property. If $d$ is a metric  then $e=\min (1,d)$ is a bounded metric that generates the same topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is, naturally enough, called the [Heine-Borel property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine-Borel_theorem#Heine-Borel_property).  It implies that $X$ is locally compact and $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: Thanks! I already stumbled upon this property and it indeed seems to be sufficient, but is it necessary? If so, then perhaps I should rephrase the question to: "under what conditions do polish spaces enjoy the Heine-Borel property?"

Comment: It's not really a property of the **space**, rather the space and the metric.  For example, you can give $\mathbb R$ a new metric which has the same topology and the same Cauchy sequences, but is bounded (and therefore the Heine-Borel property fails).